# Matlab compare 2 single column matrixes and give position

Tags: matlab, matrix, compare

I'm making a GUI in matlab to calculate ideal shifting points for a racecar.

For this I need to compare 2 single column matrixes.

```
Fwheel1 =

  1.0e+003 *

    4.5433
    4.6372
    4.6770
    4.6892
    4.7235
    4.8064
    4.9451
    5.0838
    5.2300
    5.3401
    5.4864
    5.5454
    5.5046
    5.4758
    5.5028
    5.5782
    5.6183
    5.6663
    5.7380
    5.8174
    5.8940
    5.9553
    6.0364
    6.1075
    6.0904
    5.9285
    5.7654
    5.5762
    5.3498
    5.1766
    5.0548
    4.8236
    4.6538

Fwheel2 =

  1.0e+003 *

    3.5174
    3.5901
    3.6209
    3.6304
    3.6569
    3.7211
    3.8285
    3.9358
    4.0490
    4.1343
    4.2475
    4.2932
    4.2617
    4.2393
    4.2602
    4.3186
    4.3496
    4.3868
    4.4423
    4.5038
    4.5631
    4.6105
    4.6734
    4.7284
    4.7151
    4.5898
    4.4635
    4.3170
    4.1418
    4.0077
    3.9134
    3.7344
    3.6029
```

These are the 2 matrixes. Now what I want is to compare `Fwheel1` with `Fwheel2`. I want to know at which position in the matrix Fwheel2 > Fwheel1.

So output needs to be for example 23.

I hope somebody can help me.
Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with `find`.

```
idx= find( Fwheel2 > Fwheel1);
```

If you just want the first one, or the first n, you can just

```
idx= find( Fwheel2 > Fwheel1,n);
```

Comment: In your latter solution, you might want to append `'first'`, or is that the default of `find`?

Comment: @Adriaan "The default for direction is 'first', which finds the first n nonzero elements."

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the quick respons. Now I tried this :
dF1 = find(Fwheel2 > Fwheel1)

Comment: Hi guys, Thanks for the quick respons. Now I tried this but I always get the following result.                                                                                 dF1 =

   Empty matrix: 0-by-1
This is my code.
dF1 = find(Fwheel2 > Fwheel1)                                                                                             Sorry for the stupid questions, but I'm quite new in this programming world. Kind regards

Comment: Well, then, it means that Fwheel2 is never bigger than Fwheel 1 @MertensToon

Comment: Hi, I made a interpretation mistake in my programming.bit confusingSo I made the new code but I always have errors. the first way I tried to solve it was with the find code. 
 ShiftRpm(1;1)= find( Fwheel(:,ii) > Fwheel(:,i),'first') then I get this error : ??? Error using ==> find
Second argument must be a positive scalar integer.
The second way that I tried was like this c=1;
i=1;
ii=1;

for ii = 1:6
    for i=1:400
    
        d = ii+1;
        if Fwheel(i,d)>Fwheel(i,ii);
            shift(ii) = i
        end
    end
end like this I get for 400 times shift back and I can't find the mistake

Answer (score 0):

for another method,

```
c=0;
for i=1:33
if Fwheel2(i)>Fwheel1(i)
c=c+1;
b[c]=i

end
end
```

in the b vector you have your answer

Comment: This answer is bad, as it only works for matrices 1x33.

Comment: becase his size of vector is 1*33...you can use your size or use size(Fwhee1)....:)

Comment: I understood why you put 33, its just bad programing.